# How to Fetch MUC room occupants list Inside Openfire Plugin?

Tags: plugins, openfire, multiuserchat

I am developing a openfire plugin and stuck at one point.

Below is my plugin code. I have implemented **MUCEventListener** and I am getting callbacks also. But now I want to fetch **occupants** list from **roomJID** in **messageReceived()** method. research a lot but no success. Please someone get me break through.

```
public class OfflineMessageTrigger implements Plugin,
        MUCEventListener {

    private static final Logger Log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(OfflineMessageTrigger.class);


    public OfflineMessageTrigger() {
    }

    // Plugin Interface

    public void initializePlugin(PluginManager manager, File pluginDirectory) {
        MUCEventDispatcher.addListener(this);
    }

    public void destroyPlugin() {
        MUCEventDispatcher.removeListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void roomCreated(JID roomJID) {
        Log.debug("TASOL-OfflineMessageTrigger -> MUC ->  roomCreated(): "
                + "RoomID : " + roomJID);
    }

    @Override
    public void roomDestroyed(JID roomJID) {
        Log.debug("TASOL-OfflineMessageTrigger -> MUC ->  roomDestroyed(): "
                + "RoomID : " + roomJID);
    }

    @Override
    public void occupantJoined(JID roomJID, JID user, String nickname) {
        Log.debug("TASOL-OfflineMessageTrigger -> MUC ->  occupantJoined(): "
                + "RoomID : " + roomJID + " UserID : " + user + " NickName : "
                + nickname);


    }

    @Override
    public void occupantLeft(JID roomJID, JID user) {
        Log.debug("TASOL-OfflineMessageTrigger -> MUC ->  occupantLeft(): "
                + "RoomID : " + roomJID + " UserID : " + user);

    }

    @Override
    public void nicknameChanged(JID roomJID, JID user, String oldNickname,
            String newNickname) {

    }

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(JID roomJID, JID user, String nickname,
            Message message) {



        // HERE I WANT TO FETCH OCCUPANTS LIST OF "roomJID". HOW TO GET?

    }

    @Override
    public void privateMessageRecieved(JID toJID, JID fromJID, Message message) {

    }

    @Override
    public void roomSubjectChanged(JID roomJID, JID user, String newSubject) {

    }

}
```

Thanks 
Biraj Zalavadia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this question was resolved on Openfire forum. So here is the link to the thread just in case someone will search for solution on Stackoverflow: https://igniterealtime.jiveon.com/thread/52016

Comment: Yes the question and answer given by me. Thanks for your attention. This may helps others.